How to make grub boot with a custom kernel for Macbook?
I have installed Ubuntu 24.04 on a MacBook Pro, model 2019 with intel i5 processor, but the touchpad and keyboard are not working.
I know that
a) there are numerous posts on this issue
b) there is a T2 ready distro
but I want to avoid the trouble of reinstalling it from scratch.
I have added the corresponding repo and run the command:
sudo apt install -y linux-t2-lts

However, after a reboot, the trackpad and keyboard are still completely unresponsive.
I would really appreciate any feedback on whether there is a way forward from this point.
Question edit: I see the following kernels installed
# dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-6.6.62-1-t2-noble                 6.6.62-1                                 amd64        Linux kernel, version 6.6.62-1-t2-noble
ii  linux-image-6.8.0-41-generic                  6.8.0-41.41                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.8.0-48-generic                  6.8.0-48.48                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.8.0-49-generic                  6.8.0-49.49                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-24.04                 6.8.0-49.49                              amd64        Generic Linux kernel image

However despite me running sudo update-grub I am never prompted to select kernel during boot. How can I instruct linux to use linux-image-6.6.62-1-t2-noble?

Maybe the t2 kernel is installed by Ubuntu is still using the default kernel? What is the output of uname -r?

6.8.0-49-generic

check also my update on the original question

Now it seems that the problem is Ubuntu not utilizing the kernel. I edited the title appropriately. I don't know how to change the kernel, but I am sure someone can help

found my way around the issue, posted an answer to help anyone stumbling upon this in the future

Solution:

List available kernels:

# dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-6.6.62-1-t2-noble                 6.6.62-1                                 amd64        Linux kernel, version 6.6.62-1-t2-noble
ii  linux-image-6.8.0-41-generic                  6.8.0-41.41                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.8.0-48-generic                  6.8.0-48.48                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.8.0-49-generic                  6.8.0-49.49                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-24.04                 6.8.0-49.49                              amd64        Generic Linux kernel image

For the kernel you want to use on your next reboot, check its presence in /boot/grub/grub.cfg by greping for menuentry
Citing only the line of interest for brevity
# grep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg

menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.6.62-1-t2-noble' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.6.62-1-t2-noble-advanced-53585951-09e2-44dc-9113-b81b53aafa85' {

We will need this description since we must add it in  /etc/default/grub
but first we make a backup of the said file
# cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup`

then we change the line containing the string GRUB_DEFAULT which most likely have the value 0 to
GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 6.6.62-1-t2-noble"

update grub
sudo update-grub

reboot

You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark
